# Android sqlite duplicate column on upgrade

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'll be honest. I messed up onUpgrade bit of sqlite now the app is crashing if you went from a fresh install of database version 4 to new version 5 of the app due to the last upgrade adding column xcount. The app now force closes due to duplicate column xcount...anyone know how I can fix this where the user can still retain there data?

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "data";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN prior_reminder long DEFAULT 0");
        }
        if (oldVersion < 3) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN is_repeating TEXT DEFAULT 'default'");
        }
        if (oldVersion < 5) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN xamount long DEFAULT 0");
        } else {            
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not surround sql by try catch statment.
 like this:

```
try{
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN xamount long DEFAULT 0");
}catch(Exception e){
}
```